# Findstr command prompt

Tags: cmd, command, prompt, findstr

I have some problems with findstr command in cmd. I got a text file and need to show lines that start with uppercase A but don't contain lowercase a.

Generally what I aim to find out is how to search for a string that is a part of the word or a letter in a word... It won't work whenever I try so any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findstr /r /c:"^A[^a]*$" file.txt
```

Find lines using the regular expression: Line starts with `A`, followed by a sequence of characters that does not contain the character `a` until the end of the line is reached